# Azure DevOps Appium process

Tags: azure-devops, appium

Is there a possibility for macos agent in azure devops to start the appium process in the background and continue with running tests?

I've tried adding script and cmd line but it remains stuck in "appium -p 4724" step

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about Azure DevOps but if you are running this as a shell command maybe you need to redirect the output to some file or /dev/null and put it in the background so the script continues?
```appium -p 4724 > /dev/null &``` or ```appium -p 4724 >  appium-logs.log &```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

**appium &** will continue to the next pipeline step while keeping the appium session on